# How to add CSRF Token to a HTML

Tags: html, spring-security, spring-boot, csrf

I am developing a Springboot app which has a registration and login forms working with spring security. I am using  HTML5 for the views but I do not know how I can add a CSRF Token. At the moment I am getting whitelabel error page:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this    as a fallback.
>
> Sat Oct 22 09:07:06 BST 2016
> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

This is my registration HTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>
        <bind path="username">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <input type="text" path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                            autofocus="true"/>
                <errors path="username"></errors>
            </div>
        </bind>

        <bind path="password">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                <errors path="password"></errors>
            </div>
        </bind>

        <bind path="passwordConfirm">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Confirm your password"/>
                <errors path="passwordConfirm"></errors>
            </div>
        </bind>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not want to disable CSRF from spring security since it will protect the app.

Thank you very much

Andres

EDIT:

I have tried this but did not work:

```html
        <input type="hidden" id= "csrf-token" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

error:

```
2016-10-22 11:55:56.452 ERROR 18960 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.golosinaspitufos.security.validator.UserValidator.validate(UserValidator.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at com.golosinaspitufos.security.web.UserController.registration(UserController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

User controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    userService.save(userForm);
    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());
    return "redirect:/welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model) {
    return "welcome";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dur for the response. How to add CSRF token is what I am asking. I have tried "<input type="hidden" id= "csrf-token" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>" (see my edit) but it did not work

Comment: Hi @dur. Yes that would be the question. I did not know that

Comment: Hi @dur, For a jsp, using a from from "<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>" solve the issue. What would be the equivalent solution for html?